# My @Autowired service always null when I give no value for @RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired, request-mapping

I have a JSP page that called a method from a controller in my Hibernate project

**Here's some of my code in JSP page:**

```
...
<jsp:useBean id="acl" scope="request" class="com.angelina.token.controller.AccessControlListsController"/>
     ...
            <c:if test="<c:if test="${acl.allowView(session,7)}">">
            <a style="font-size:12px;" href="<c:url value="/admin/account/"/>">Account Balance</a>
            </c:if>
     ...
```

**Here's some of my Controller**

```
...
@Autowired
private AccessControlListsService aclService;
@Autowired
private UsersService usersService;
...
@RequestMapping(value="")
@ResponseBody
public boolean allowView(HttpSession session, Integer permissionId) throws Exception {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String userName = auth.getName();
        Users users = usersService.findByUserName(userName).get(0);
        Integer roleId = users.getRoles().getId();
        Boolean status = aclService.getByRoleIdAndPermissionId(roleId, permissionId).getCanView();
        return status;
}
...
```

`usersService` is an Service object when I called method `allowView(HttpSession session, Integer permissionId)` from a JSP page `usersService` always return null.

**Does Anyone have any idea on what should I do so that my object service not return null?**

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Because you shouldn't be calling that method from a JSP, you shouldn't put java code in your JSP.

Comment: yeah you right. As for now I did a hard way to  put method  `allowView(HttpSession session, Integer permissionId)` into each controller I have and throw param value from url

Comment: imho you are trying to apply security in a somewhat convoluted way. Use Spring Security do that for you and stop putting java code i.e. script lets into  your code.

Comment: I already use Spring Security before and I want to change existing spring security into a managable access control list

Comment: Ehrm.... What you are currently doing is, imho hardly manageable...

Answer (score 0):

try to look for in your spring context if you have a component-scan tag

sth like :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.com.******
```